# Moq generic Repository - TARGETPARAMETERCOUNTEXCEPTION

Tags: c#, include, mocking, repository, moq

I am Mocking a generic repository and have just added a second argument to my Retrieve method allowing me to pass include strings for object properties, I'm a bit stuck on how to Mock this and am getting a `TargetParameterCountException`.

If anyone could nudge me in the right direction, that would be great.

Interface:

```
IQueryable<T> Retrieve(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

IQueryable<T> Retrieve(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, IEnumerable<string> includes);
```

Moq:

```
var mActionRepository = new Mock<IRepository<ContainerAction>>();
mActionRepository.Setup(m => m.Retrieve(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ContainerAction, bool>>>()))
    .Returns<Expression<Func<ContainerAction, bool>>>(queryable.Where);

mActionRepository.Setup(m => m.Retrieve(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ContainerAction, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>()))
    .Returns<Expression<Func<ContainerAction, bool>>>(queryable.Where);
```

The first Moq worked, the second doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Returns` method you need to specify all the argument types of the mocked method as generic arguments.

So you are missing the `IEnumerable<string>` in your second `Returns` call that is why you get the `TargetParameterCountException`.

So your second `Returns` should look like this:

```cs
mActionRepository.Setup(m => m.Retrieve(
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ContainerAction, bool>>>(), 
    It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>()))
    .Returns<Expression<Func<ContainerAction, bool>>, IEnumerable<string>>(
        (predicate, includes) => queryable.Where(predicate));
```